# Construct a switch in environment to make the body working or not

Tags: environments, tex-core, latex3, comments

I want to make a local switch by the type of argument `s` in the environment defination by '\NewDocumentEnvironment`.

If the first argument of the new environment is `star`(switch on), all codes inside the environment would be commented. If no star is given(switch off), all codes inside would be running normally. In this way, it will be convenient for codes test.

Could anyone help me with this? It's better to be without any further packages.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% only for test

\NewDocumentEnvironment{switchenv}{s}{...}{...}%how to do?
\begin{document}
% Test 1: all codes inside switchenv working in normal way
\begin{switchenv}
some code\\
\makeatletter\@for\i:={1,2,3}\do{(\i)}\makeatother
\par
some code\\
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_item:nn {1in ,2in ,3in}{2}\\
\ExplSyntaxOff
some code\\
\begin{lstlisting}
  \for
\end{lstlisting}
\end{switchenv}
\vskip3ex

% Test 2:  all codes inside switchenv be commented
|\begin{switchenv}*
some code\\
\makeatletter\@for\i:={1,2,3}\do{(\i)}\makeatother
\par
some code\\
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_item:nn {1in ,2in ,3in}{2}\\
\ExplSyntaxOff
some code\\
\begin{lstlisting}
  \for
\end{lstlisting}
\end{switchenv}|

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you committed to the `*` syntax which complicates things, also (and much simpler) `*` forms of environments are usually `\begin{tabular*}` not `\begin{tabular}*`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`*` forms of environments have the `*` in the name (`tabular*`, `align*`, etc)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% only for test
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for |

\NewDocumentEnvironment{switchenv*}{+b}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{switchenv}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
% Test 1: all codes inside switchenv working in normal way
\begin{switchenv}
some code\\
\makeatletter\@for\i:={1,2,3}\do{(\i)}\makeatother
\par
some code\\
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_item:nn {1in ,2in ,3in}{2}\\
\ExplSyntaxOff
some code% uderfull hbox\\
\begin{lstlisting}
  \for
\end{lstlisting}
\end{switchenv}
\vskip3ex

% Test 2:  all codes inside switchenv be commented
|\begin{switchenv*}
some code\\
\makeatletter\@for\i:={1,2,3}\do{(\i)}\makeatother
\par
some code\\
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_item:nn {1in ,2in ,3in}{2}\\
\ExplSyntaxOff
some code% uderfull hbox\\
\begin{lstlisting}
  \for
\end{lstlisting}
\end{switchenv*}|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle. The manual says `\NewDocumentEnvironment {<environment>} {<arg spec>}
{<start code>} {<end code>}`. And I tries `\NewDocumentEnvironment{aaa}{s}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{***}{}}{}`  `\begin{aaa}* abc\end{aaa}`, it works well. Do I wrongly comprehend the syntzx?

Comment: You can define a `*` with `s` but it's unexpected syntax for a user (I know of no latex or package defined environment that does that, and in this particular case it complicates things as it is _inside_ the body and you want to change the interpretation of the body depending on its value @lyl

Comment: For `\begin{switch*}...\end{switch*}`, the modification from non-star to star or vice versa has to be done two times(at the place of begin, and at the place of end). It is boring especially when the codes in the environment is very long(over a screen). That's the reason why I would like the version `\begin{switch}*...\end{switch}`(only add/remove the star once). Can I get it? Or except the `s` any other similar solution by which the modification of the `local switch` can be done only once?

Comment: if you want just one place, define `\cmdyes` to be  `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{switchenv*}{+b}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}` and `\cmdno` to be `\RenewDocumentEnvironment{switchenv}{}{}{}`  then `\cmdyes\begin{switchenv]...` @lyl